# Adding Integers to HashMap

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` to which I am adding integers from an array. The key is the integer and the value is the number of duplicates of the integer. When I iterate through the `HashMap` to get the keys in the `HashMap` they seem to be in random order. Is there any particular order in which these keys are added ? This is how I am iterating through.

```
       Set<String> a = names.keySet();
        Iterator i = a.iterator();

        while(i.hasNext())
            String t = (String) i.next();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, `HashMap` returns entries in a nondeterministic (unpredictable/unreliable) order. If you want entries to appear in order by key (so, `2` before `3`), use a `TreeMap` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)). If you want entries to appear in order by initial insertion, use a `LinkedHashMap` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)).

---

**Edited to add:** You say that "the key is the integer", but then you use `String` everywhere. Note that the string `"123"` sorts *before* the string `"23"`, just as `"abc"` would sort before `"bc"`. If you want your keys treated as numbers, e.g. by being sorted in numeric order, then you should be using a numeric type, such as `Integer`, rather than `String`. (It's technically possible to give your `TreeMap` a `Comparator<String>` that compares string-valued keys by examining their contents and doing an integer comparison, but I don't think you want to do that.)

Comment: I observed using a LinkedHashMap stores the key in the given order. I tried using a TreeMap and it didn't exactly return the keys in sorted order. Would you be able to provide an example ?

Comment: @RaghavShankar `TreeMap` will guarantee the keys are lexicographical ascending as that is the order imposed by `String.compareTo`.

Comment: @RaghavShankar: It's as veer says. I've edited my answer to explain this.

Answer (score 2):

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> This class (HashMap) makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time

You can use a [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) if you'd like them in "natural order".

If you want the `Iterator` to return the keys in the order they were added, you could [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the
>   order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order)

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` also supports access-ordering.